# I don't know why it's throwing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out why is this error showing, but I can't. I think that everything's okay, but at some point the value "i" at readTest is == 2. Which is not supposed to... listW has 2 objects, and the "i" should only be 0 and 1. I don't where the 2 is coming from. Am I making anything wrong? I've done some testing and the i=2 only happens at readTest. What's happening?

Thank you for your attention guys

```
public void readTest(int i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != leftListList[i].getKeyValues().Length; j++)
            {
                string read = ws.Read(listW[i], wi[i].GetKey(), leftListList[i].getKeyValues()[j]);
                WsRead wsRead = wi[i].BuildRead(read, leftListList[i].getKeyValues()[j]);
                readList.Add(wsRead);

                Console.WriteLine("READ: " + leftListList[i].getKeyValues()[j]);
            }
        }

        public void threadTest()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != listW.Length; i++)
            {
                    Thread t = new Thread(() => readTest(i));
                    t.Start();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have a wild `else` running around.

Comment: look into `foreach` loops, they'd make your code way more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a *local* variable, say `index`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listW.Length; i++) // i < listW.Length is more readable
{
    int index = i;
    ...
    else 
    {
        // now each thread has its own index
        Thread t = new Thread(() => readTest(index));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

when `Thread` finally *starts* (it *takes time* to create a new thread), the loop is *completed* and thus `i == 2`

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much! You're my lifesaver!